# how to mark row on gridview by any value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have gridview that contain:

```
Fname|Born
aa   |03/05
bb   |19/01
cc   |03/08
dd   |19/01
```

if today is: `19/01/2011`  how to mark in red color the 2 rows that Satisfies the condition ?

in C# asp.net

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.MyGridView.RowDataBound += (s, ea) =>
{
 if (ea.Row.Cells[1].Text.Contains(string.Format("{0}/0{1}", DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month)))
 {
  ea.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
 }
};
this.MyGridView.DataBind();
```

This does what you want.

Notice the string.format has a 0 which shouldn't be there. This is because DateTime.Now.Month returns 1 instead of 01.

[edit]

Noticed sometime ago that there's a better way to compare the date to your value using

```
if (ea.Row.Cells[1].Text.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString(MM/dd)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try using RowDataBound  event of the grid to test the date column 
if (e.row.cell[1]=...)
, and from there you can access the e.Row.BackColor= ...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a good place to start, if you want to change design-settings of a datagridview programmatically is using the `datagridview.CellFormatting-Event`

```
        private void _dgvDb_CellFormatting(Object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e){
        if (e.Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()))
        {
            switch (_dgvDb.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
            {
                case "YOUR_COLUMNNAME":
                    if("value==yourChosenValue"){

                    }
                break;
                case "else":
                }
         }
  }
```